# JS error: play is not a function

Tags: javascript

function play(id, song)
    {
     alert(id+song);
    }

```
 <img id="oi1" class="oi" src="/images/miniplay.png" alt="Play" onclick="play(24, '325s2sq2h');"/>
 <img id="oi2" class="oi" src="/images/miniplay.png" alt="Play" onclick="play(35, 'skf8s2n2');"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Firebug gives an error

> play is not a function [Break on this
>   error] play (24, "325s2sq2h");

How fix it? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with the `img` with `id="play"` - it's conflicting with your function name;  rename one or the other

Comment: Agreed, I was just about to post the same answer. However, I'm not quite sure if this is to be considered a browser bug or correct behaviour; do DOM `id` names not belong in a different namespace than JavaScript code?

Comment: @stakx - I was wondering the same thing and this is what I found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415747/javascript-function-and-form-name-conflict

Answer (score 0):

Either rename the function, or change the id of the first image. Currently they are both `play`, so they conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Marek's right. That must b the one ;)