# show form elements using javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick

Can anyone please help me through this....
I have two input fields in my form . One of which is hidden and I want to show it using a button. Now when i tried to show it using onClick() function its not responding...

can anyone give me code snippet to do so....

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>
function show()
{
document.getElementById('passwd').style.display="block" ;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="demo.html" >
<input type="text" name="user" />
<br />
<input type="text" id="passwd" name="password"  style="display:none;" />
<input type="button" onClick="show()" name="show" value="show" />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="OK" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

plz help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because of your `<input>` declaration:

```
<input type="button" onClick="show()" name="show" value="show" />
```

When you call `show()` JavaScript will attempt to resolve the symbol `show` first; because you're calling `show()` from inlined code, **the resolution takes place in `document`**,  which attempts to resolve the symbol based on the `name` or `id` attribute of your input box.

**Solutions**

Rename the button:

```
<input type="button" onClick="show()" name="showbutton" value="show" />
```

Rename the function:

```
function showPasswordInputBox()
{
  // your code here
}

<input type="button" onClick="showPasswordInputBox()" name="show" value="show" />
```

Don't use in-line code:

```
function show()
{
  // whatever
}

var showButton = document.getElementsByName('show')[0];

showButton.addEventListener('click', show, false);
```

**See also**

[Don't give event handler the same name as a field!](http://www.xinotes.org/notes/note/698/)

[Javascript Function and Form Name conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415747/javascript-function-and-form-name-conflict)

Comment: Why this strange behaviour ?

Comment: @Jashwant There's an exact reason for it, but pragmatically it's just browser quirkiness :)

Comment: Thanks Jack, Guffa's answer on second link explains it all :)

Comment: @Jashwant Yeah, gives me more ammunition to advocate against inline code :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with naming convention of show() function in javascript. Because just change the name to show1(). it'll work

```
function show1()
{
 alert("ok");
}
<input type="button"  name="show" value="show" onclick="show1()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **jquery** and write following code: `$("#passwd").show()`
or you can use `addClass('here_css_class')` and css code `.here_css_class{
display: block
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
try this 

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>
function show()
{
document.getElementById('passwd').style.display="block" ;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="demo.html" >
<input type="text" name="user" />
<br />
<input type="text" id="passwd" name="password"  style="display:none;" />
**<button onClick="show()" >Show</button>**
<br />
<input type="submit" value="OK" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to use this:

```
onClick="javascript:show();"
```

or simply

```
onClick="show();"
```

Basically, just add the semi-colon :)

Comment: You don't need to add a semi-colon (although it is good style to do so) as JavaScript has semi-colon insertion which will take care of it there. The label you've added (`javascript:`) is entirely useless as there is no loop to break or continue from.

Comment: My Bad... @PradipBorde , please see Jack's answer above. Thanks Quentin for pointing it out

Comment: Yeah... the name of the functon needs to be changed here