# javascript onclick function call passing form name without quotes results

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function calledHere(value) { console.log(value); }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="test">
            <input type="button" value="click!" onclick="calledHere(test);" >
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

From the above code, in the onclick call passed wrongly the form name without quotes. But, the output displays the whole form DOM element. Don't know how it got the form element.

Any help will be more useful for my learning on javascript side.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: You should probably change it to `<input type="button" value="click!" onclick="calledHere('test');">`

Comment: In future, if you add your code to jsfiddle.net it makes it easier for other members to give you an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already got the form element in your 'value' variable. The reason you're seeing the element's html logged is because console.log calls the .toString() method on the element.

This code demonstrates that 'value' references the form element:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function calledHere(value) { value.style.backgroundColor = "red" }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="test">
            <input type="button" value="click!" onclick="calledHere(test);" >
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/John_C/KZ3KR/

This answer explains the scope of the variable; why you can pass the form name to the function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1416157/1588990